# How to build an expression in a total row in MS Access

Tags: vba, ms-access

In MS Access I need to build an expression in the total row of a table and I don't know how to do it.

for example the 2nd column of this table says whether the 1st column is positive or negative

Number ......... Sign

10...............pos

-5...............neg

20...............pos

-15..............neg

now in total row the 1st column is sum and the 2nd is the sign of the sum

10...............pos

I have searched the net and my training resources but I couldn't find a clue
I would be glad if someone help me

Comment: Can't build an expression in Total row of table. All you can do is use the aggregate functions provided. If you need to do more than that then build a report using Sorting & Grouping features and aggregate calcs in group and report header/footer sections.

Comment: Why do you have a table that stores the sign of another value?

Comment: tables have a total row????  as far as i know, tables hold records only.

Comment: Use a form set to _datagridview_. Here you can add a Totals row.

Comment: @YowE3K that was an example

Comment: @jsotola In MSAccess, you can display a total row.  It isn't actually stored as data, just displayed in the GUI.

Comment: thanks everyone... at least I know that It can not happen in table

Comment: @jsotola yes tables can have total row